# I want to add the variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any solution to my problem??
My code:-

```
import random

for val in range(1,201):
    val = str(val)
    a + val = random.randint(0,99)
    b + val = random.randint(0,99)
    c + val = random.randint(0,99)
```

## I want result to be a1 = random number, b2 = random number, c3 = random number and so on upto 200

Thanks for any assistance in advance

Comment: why you are converting to string in for loop??

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, errors, output, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text here. Take time to check [ask]. Make sure you provide [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dictionaries.

```
import string
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
dictVars = {y[0]+str(x+1):y[1] for x,y in enumerate(zip(letters,list(range(1,3))))}
```

**output**

```
{'a1': 1, 'b2': 2}
```

Then search through this to find each variables value

```
print(dictVars['a1'])
```

**output**

```
1
```

Comment: Your answer is not useful in this case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7h9.png

Answer (score 0):

Just use arrays instead

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
for val in range(1,41):
    a.append(1)
    b.append(2)
    c.append(3)
```

Access using `a[n-1]` for any value of n in the range

Comment: This is not real nice if the user wants 26 variables.

Comment: I agree - didn't realize the user might want that just based on the picture. I like your solution for more than a few letters

Comment: True, you have a good point. User is only asking for 3.